# Firebase signInWithRedirect not working in chrome incognito?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome, firebase-authentication

I'm using the following code to prompt a google auth login with redirect:

```
        var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        provider.setCustomParameters({
            prompt: 'select_account'
        });
        firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
```

I listen to auth callbacks in a firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged - however it doesn't get called in chrome incognito.

However it works fine even in incognito with firebase.auth().signinWithPopup

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?