# Firebase authentication with signInWithRedirect at web showing Not initialized

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome, firefox, firebase-authentication

When using Firebase authentication with signInWithRedirect for example with Sigh in with Google, it returns first to empty white page showing just few words: "Not initialized..". There is no error in the console. After a second or so it returns to loginpage the whole process started from.

This happens on Firefox, but not on Chrome (in cocole, no errors and all goes as expected). Also, with Firefox all works with signInWithPopup. From previous posts I found something related from

[Firebase signInWithRedirect not working in chrome incognito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68690900/firebase-signinwithredirect-not-working-in-chrome-incognito)

but there was no answers to that one so I am posting another one.

If I try login with GitHub, same results except the blank page with "Not initialized.." comes before it shows the login at GitHub and returns without showing the login (with Google it does the login, and shows that on the way back). And again, with Chrome no problemo.

So it seems it has something to do with chrome incognito (didn't know it was using that but according to meds (or Frank van Puffelen ?) at the other thread, it might be related). How could it be avoided?

To summarize, it works with signInWithPopup with Firefox too, and with signInWithRedirect only with Chrome or at least not working with Firefox (haven't tried other browsers yet). Do I need to intialize the auth with some specific options or is this a bug with firebase or firefox?

Anyway, basically it goes as this:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { GoogleAuthProvider, getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'XXX',
  authDomain: 'XXX',
  projectId: 'XXX',
  storageBucket: 'XXX',
  messagingSenderId: ''XXX',
  appId: ''XXX'
};

const fire_app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(fire_app);

const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider); // All OK
...
signInWithRedirect(auth, provider); // Not ok with Firefox, but ok with chrome
...
const result = await getRedirectResult(auth); // thus fails with firefox, ok with chrome
```